# I can't override Base class's method because my derived class is templatised

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I try to override the base class function but because I have templatised its child/derived/sub class I can't override the function depending on which type I instantiate the template with.

```
struct BaseType
{
    virtual double getPropertyValue() = 0; 
};

template <typename T>
struct NumberType : BaseType
{
    T propertyValue;
    T getPropertyValue() override { return propertyValue; }  // I would like this to return whatever T is.
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<BaseType*> vectr;
    NumberType<double> doubleType;  // This is fine, overrides the base function
    NumberType<int> intType;    // Has no overrider, won't compile
}
```

So I thought maybe I could templatise also the Base class, so that the base class function returns T also. But if I do this I won't be able to keep them in a container or point to them, because they'll all be of different Base< type> types.

I also thought about templatising Base and having it inherit from an even higher parent (which isn't templatised), but I run into the same problem.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: "*I can't override Base class's method because my derived class is templatised*" That is not the reason you can't override.

Comment: Sorry, I realise how that sounded, you're right. Not just because I've templatised it, because I've got return types that depend on the template argument.

Comment: Why do you *need* to override a pure virtual function? Looks like to me that you're mixing static and dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Why do you want to put different types into the same container? You will not be able to use them properly because of the type differences. You can actually use `template <class T> std::vector<NumberType<T>> numbers;` to not lose type information.

Comment: I was experimenting with abstracting away the different data types so I could have a container of different types, type erasure I think they call it? It was for creating my own scripting thing where you could make your own classes dynamically at runtime, but it looks like this is not possible.

Comment: It's interesting to see this question asked, because I've seen more than a few developers try this (at work, and probably an equal number of StackOverflow questions). Perhaps it implies that the language encourages some kind of mental model that implies something like this would work. I don't think I can attribute it to "someone wanting to have their cake and eat it, too" anymore, by which I mean getting all the tasty benefits of a single container of polymorphic type while also getting the benefits of derived class-specific behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this if the return value `T` is *covariant* with the return value of the pure virtual function. But sadly a `T` will not, in general, be covariant with a `double`.

Accepting that you're mixing up static and dynamic polymorphism techniques, which might be a design flaw, you could define

```
struct Cov {};
```

with

```
struct BaseType
{
    virtual Cov& getPropertyValue() = 0; 
};
```

Then,

```
template <typename T>
struct NumberType : BaseType
{
    T propertyValue;
    T& getPropertyValue() override { return propertyValue; }
};
```

where `T` is a child class of `Cov`: this relationship means that `T&` is a return type that's covariant with `Cov&`, and so compilation will succeed.  Doing it this way also obviates a value copy of `T` being taken. You might also find it convenient to build *conversion* operators for the various `T`s that end up getting built that have primitive type return values.

You can also introduce `const` reference return types to suit the exact requirements.

Comment: From the example code in the answer, neither `int` nor `double` are child class of `Cov`. It won't solve the problem without an extra bit of machinery that isn't explained in the answer.

Comment: That's very very interesting. Covariant, that's the word Visual Studio used, said it had to be covariant. This looks very interesting, I'm going to see what I can do.

Comment: @skypjack Yes, that's the first thing I thought, then I thought I'll just wrap the primitive data types in classes. Wow, there are endless solutions. OK, it's probably all a bad idea, but still, I like seeing how crazy this can get.

Comment: If you do wrap primitive types in classes, then you could also define *conversion* operators in those classes to yield the primitives!

Comment: @Zebrafish Well, if you are free to change the definitions of _everything_, then yes: there are a lot of different solutions.

Comment: But what would you **do** with a reference to `Cov`? It's an empty class. Can you invent a sensible interface for it?

Comment: @n.m. It's difficult to submit a comprehensive solution without more details. My aim of this answer is to describe the reason for this error, introduce the correct terminology and describe how you might embark on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`BaseType` has a contract that is binding for all its descendants. It says says that `getPropertyValue` returns `double`. `NumberType` doesn't get to modify the contract, it's set in stone.

Let's pretend the contract is not there.

```
BaseType& base = BaseContainer.getSome();

// base can be NumberType<complex> or 
// or NumberType<tensor<double,4,4,4>> or NumberType<padic<5>>
// or a type that is not even thought of yet 
// as of now.

 what = base.getPropertyValue(); // how should 'what' be declared?
```

There's no way to use the result of `base.getPropertyValue()` if we don't know what it is.

Making the return type covariant doesn't really help. It just shifts the problem from `BaseType` to whatever base class `BaseType::getPropertyValue()` returns.

You need to come up with a usable interface of `BaseType` and stick to it in all descendant classes.